# Aligning elements to the left and the right

Tags: html, css, layout

A client wants a navigation layout as shown below:

[image: How the menu works]

As you can see, it is made up of "main links" and "sub links". There can be any number of each, and the text content may change. The width of the menu container will change depending on the page size.

God bless the designers, who decided to align the left and right edges of these links, and keep a consistent amount of space between each one. The client is *adamant* that this is how the navigation is made.

So, the question is: how can this be done? I've tried it with tables (CSS and HTML), but while they align over the total length, the text in the cells doesn't align on the right hand side.

The current solution is to put a custom amount of padding on the elements until they line up, but obviously this is a rubbish solution. I don't want to end up having to measure things with Javascript to lay them out, so if anyone knows of a smart way to get this done, I'd certainly appreciate it.

Comment: Surely you only need to worry about the last link..and `text-align:right` would solve that?

Comment: I think hes confused. I think he wants the menu centered and to fill the entire top of the screen evenly.

Comment: @Paulie_D That wouldn't satisfy the "consistent amount of space between each [link]" part, though.

Comment: @VictorioBerra It needs to be center, left and right aligned :(

Comment: No it won't but that's basically (AFAIK) impossible without JS.

Answer (score 1):

I do think CSS tables will get you most of the way.

You merely have to align the text of the first and last elements of each

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KhC94/5/)

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul {
    padding: 0 3px;
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}
.menu-list li {
    height: 45px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f69b58;
    display:table-cell;
    /* add this */
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.menu-list li:first-child {
    text-align:left;
}

.menu-list li:last-child {
    text-align:right;
}

.menu-list li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-list li:active {
    color:black;
    background-color: #3EAEE9;
}
.menu-list li:hover {
    background:#3eaee9;
}
.menu-list li.current {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(7, 80, 158), rgb(6, 101, 243));
    background-color: #3EAEE9;
}
```

**NOTE: This will NOT make the distance between each link the same, for that you will (almost certainly) require JS.**

Comment: Re: the note - that's what I feared. I'm giving something using `text-align: justify` and non-breaking spaces a go.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something which concerns the right amount of divs to align the text in the center. I've made a solution in fiddle as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/denWG/32/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="in_container">
       <a href="" class="name">Example Exampleson</a>
    </div>
    <div class="in_container">
       <a href="" class="title">Producer</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.in_container{
    text-align: center;  
}

}
.name {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't align the left and right edges, though?